# adjusting default margins

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an image in a header, and when i wrap the `<img>` in a `<a>` tag the image is displaced.  I am assuming that the `<a>` tag has default margins or padding that is causing this.  How do you remove the default margins or padding of the `<a>` tag in jquery-mobile?

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="shadow">
        <a href="#CheckInPage" data-role="none" id="newheader">
            <img id="goHeaderLogo" src="images/go.gif" alt="go Logo"/>
        </a>
        <h2>Locations Near Me</h2>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<script>
        $('#newheader').css("margin",'0px');
    </script>
```

Comment: jquery mobile does a lot of change to your code wrapping it in several containers. So, first of all, see how is wrapped your image and show us a demo using jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to figure out what styles you need to modify is to inspect the individual elements with something like firebug or the browser's developer tools

try this (I used `margin-left: 50px` to see better the difference)

```
 <style>
  .ui-header .ui-btn-left {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
 </style>
```

and you get this
[image]